# Return coordinates based on the location using elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to elastic search. I need to return latitude and longitude based on the location.if is there any way to do this please explain in some details.

Comment: Do you intend to return  documents where stored lat long are in with given distance of queried lat long.

Comment: First, take a look at : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html the documentation is pretty clear.